# Setting up the command gdb on windows

Tags: windows, gdb, valgrind

Well I am relatively new in computer's world, and I learned programming on a virtual machine using linux S.O. I am using minGW32 command prompt, and I can compile and run my c codes as needed, however I recently installed gdb debugger (for debugging my programms), and it is bit uncomfortable to write:

```
"c:\mingw\bin\gdb.exe" exe_name
```

in order to debug my programs. Is there a way for having something like:

```
gdb exe_name
```

like in linux?

Thanks in advance.

extra question: And the same for valgrind?

best regards

Comment: You can add "c:\mingw\bin\" to your Windows PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the path `"c:\mingw\bin"` in your **environment variable**. This way whenever you type **gdb** on command prompt, it would search from the above path.

> And the same for valgrind?

Till date Valgrind does not run on Windows platform.